# Define customized conversion set in ConTeXt based on Lua command

Tags: numbering, lists, context

According to ConTeXt Garden (https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/defineconversion) a custom conversion can be define using a list. Example:

```
\defineconversion[inventory][<3,!,\math{\therefore},?]
```

will use `<3` for 1, `!` for 2 and so on. However it is a painful task when a larger list is needed. If I need a conversion based in, e.g., a Lua function, the following

```
\startluacode
function myfunction(n)
  -- return something 
end
\stopluacode
\def\myfunction#1\directlua{context(myfunction(n))}
```

won't work in

```
\defineconversion[myfunction][\myfunction]
```

Reading the mailing list was worthless, as conversions are written in `core-con.lua` and the solutions for specific cases (Spanish numerals, etc.) require a time before the conversion is incorporated in the file. Is there a solution which doesn't implies tweak `core-con.lua` nor manually writing each element of the conversion set?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define the whole conversion in Lua.

```
\starttext

\startluacode
```

```lua
local function myfunction(n)
    local t = { "<3", "!", "\\math{\\therefore}", "?" }
    return t[n]
end

interfaces.implement {
    name = "myfunction",
    actions = { myfunction, context },
    arguments = "integer",
}
```

```
\stopluacode
\unprotect
\def\myfunction#1{\clf_myfunction\numexpr#1\relax}
\protect

\defineconversion[inventory][\myfunction]

\startitemize[inventory][stopper=,width=2em]
    \item foo
    \item bar
    \item baz
\stopitemize

\stoptext
```

[image]

In principle you can also use the `\directlua` approach from you question but I find that ugly.

```
\startluacode
```

```lua
function userdata.myfunction(n)
    assert(type(n) == "number")
    local t = { "<3", "!", "\\math{\\therefore}", "?" }
    context(t[n])
end
```

```
\stopluacode
\def\myfunction#1{\ctxlua{userdata.myfunction(\number\numexpr#1\relax)}}
```